# How to install ubuntu from desktop w/o internet access?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu on a netbook without a CD drive. I first attempted a flash drive, but it did not work, so I decided to use the flash drive to transfer the application that can install from the desktop.

However, this is a secondhand school computer that needs its borderline spyware security suite wiped before it can access the internet, so I cannot use the install from desktop application.

Do I have any other options? I do have access to an external CD drive that I could try, but I am unconvinced that I would get different results since it would have to go through a USB port.

Any and all input is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need Internet access to install Ubuntu. You only need a LiveCD or LiveUSB.

Make sure that you created a bootable USB (flash drive). You can also try download the Ubuntu iso (or you already have it) burn that to a CD to create a LiveCD using the school computer, then boot from that CD and create a LiveUSB via **Startup Disk Creator** which you can launch while running Ubuntu with the LiveCD. Then try the created LiveUSB on your netbook.

Answer (score 1):

To install Ubuntu, you either use:

- [LiveCD (needs CD-ROM Drive)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GettingUbuntu).
- [USBStickQuick (needs USB boot capabilities)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick)
- [From Windows (if windows installed on the target computer)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows).

A more comprehensive documentation on the subject and some other installation methods can be found at:

[Ubuntu Installation - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)

---

Alternatively, you can remove the HDD from your laptop and place it on another laptop with CD-ROM or USB boot capabilities, to swipe the HDD contents, and then install the Ubuntu on it.

After installed return the HDD to the original laptop.

---

### EDITED

By your comment regarding the hardware specifications for the mentioned Netbook, it seems to be this Asus Eee PC 1215P:

[image]

The Ubuntu installation is documented as proven to work at:

[HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks/#Asus_Eee_PC_1215P)

For this netbook, you can access the BIOS and change the boot order to move and select the USB boot as the first option:

1. Start the Eee PC and press < F2 > repeatedly during boot-up to show the POST screen to enter the BIOS setup. When booting, you can tapping the  key to enter the BIOS setting.
2. Move cursor to choose "Boot" and disable the "Boot Booster".
3. Select the 'Boot Device Priority' and set 'Removable Device' as the 1st Boot Device.
4. Press < F10 > to save your changes and exit.

[image]

Comment: Most netbooks wont allow HDD removal, as you'd have to take apart the entire machine to get at the HDD.  I've had to do a few of these things like that, i know that most of them are like that..

Comment: Thanks for the input, Zuul and Lord of Time. I tried to boot from windows, but I do not have internet access due to the aforementioned security suite. Should I give mounting the .iso a try?

Comment: @TomP. Yes, try it. But can you provide the netbook brand and model for a more detailed help!

Comment: @Zuul - Hilariously, I am not even sure what brand and model it is. Here are a few of its specs:

proc:intel atom 1.666 45nm technology
m/b: asustek computer inc 1215sp
display adapter: hsd121phw1
graphics: intel (r) graphics media accelerator 3150
hd: 313gb seagate st9320325as (sata)
webcam: usb 2.0 uvc vga WebCam
wireless: Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter

Another side note, it took me entirely too long to realize that there are two hard drives. I started to take the machine apart and realized this, and that I had no idea which was the slave and which was the master.

Thanks again!

Comment: @LordofTime Yap, I know, for me is like _"a walk in the park"_, didn't thought that far! My bad :)